# Raspberry Pi 3 Model B - Windows IoT RDP Client

Tags: networking, windows-iot, c#

### UPDATE

I have a RPI3B running Raspbian with rdesktop fully working.

Now I want it to launch the remote session immediately after logon. There are no "users" on the Raspbian side and my Windows server handle the credential checks.

---

### What I've Done

So far the only thing I've tried is adding the *rdesktop* command to the *.bashrc* file, but that didn't work...

So how can I do this?

---

### Additional Requests

1. Is it possible to handle RDP using Windows 10 IoT? The documentation that I've found on this indicates it's not - however it's mostly old data.
2. If the issue is drivers for IoT, does anyone know what is required to develop these? And, is there anyone who'd be interested in helping/doing this?

Comment: What is it, that you want to do? Exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, you can't use RDP on windows IoT the way you know it. It isn't designed for this purpose.

As for your additional request: Well I wouldn't bothering, and really there's no desktop you could use anyway. So the answer is still no!

---

There's Windows IoT remote client which will show you what you see when you connect your rpi via hdmi but that's not remote desktop like Windows Server ones

Comment: Yes this is true. There is NO desktop to RDP into. You can SSH into the Pi but all you get is the powershell command line. IoT is just meant to run your App on it, with whatever GUI you make. Technically, its possible to create a desktop like GUI and build in some RDP into that.. but I am not sure if anybody is working on such a project yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try Windows IOT Remote client:
[link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/windows-iot-remote-client/9nblggh5mnxz)